# User Friendly GUI based 3d PDE solving software

Tags: pde, software

I'm searching for software which can solve 3d IBVP like PDEtool in Matlab (user-friendly GUI, easy to learn how to use). What could you advise to me? (ANSYS,COMSOL,OpenFOAM are too difficult for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider [PDE2D](http://www.pde2d.com).  Despite the name, it also applies to 3D problems.  The advantage of this software is that it does provide a GUI based interface.  You can download and use a free trial version for an unlimited amount of time, but there are limitations to the size of the problems that you can solve in the free version.